# Binding to property on child scope

Tags: angularjs, scope

I have an angular application using Angular Router.

My main view is a tabbed view, which has 10 tabs defined in it. For each tab there is a named view for the angular router to inject templates into. Each tab knows nothing about its content, other than a header which is configured through state definition.

```
state('personView', {
            route: "people/:personId/",
            views: {
                   "tab1": {
                          tabConfig: {
                             name: 'tab1',
                             icon: 'info_outline'
                          }
                          template: "person-details.tpl",
                          controller: 'personDetailsController as vm'
                    },
                    "tab2": {
                          tabConfig: {
                             name: 'tab2',
                             icon: 'info_outline'
                          }
                          template: "children-details.tpl",
                          controller: 'childrenDetailsController as vm'
                    }
                }})
```

What I would like to do is include a counter in the tab header which displays how many items are inside each tab. using above example, if there were 4 children, I would like the tab header to display the number 4 as a badge. But the knowledge of the children is that of the childrenDetailsController and that alone.

So how best to get the count up into the tabbed header without giving my childrenDetailsController the knowledge that it is being used in a tabbed template? Ideally, I would configure the tabbed view to 'look into' the childDetailsController and pull out a certain property, which could be used for the counter. But binding into child scopes is not something I am familiar with.

Answer (score 1):

```
$state.get()
```

get(stateName) - A method for retrieving the configuration object for any state, by passing the name as a string.

get() - Returns an array of all state config objects.

or

```
$state.current
```

Comment: I don't want the state config object - I want access a property on the scope of a child state from a parent scope. The child view is nested.